# choosing unique subsets of length 3 using vba

Tags: vba, excel

i am trying to generate unique subsets of length 3 from integers ranging from 1 to 6. i have  played around with many versions of my script below but always seem to hit some kind of an issue. it would be great if somebody could give me some pointers. thanks.

```
Sub permuteTest()

num = 6
cRow = 1

For i = 1 To num - 2

    For j = 2 To num - 1

        For k = 3 To num

            Cells(cRow, 1).Value = i
            Cells(cRow, 2).Value = j
            Cells(cRow, 3).Value = k

            cRow = cRow + 1

        Next k
    Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like so:

```
Sub permuteTest()

num = 6
cRow = 1

    For i = 1 To num - 2
        For j = i + 1 To num - 1
            For k = j + 1 To num
                Cells(cRow, 1).Value = i
                Cells(cRow, 2).Value = j
                Cells(cRow, 3).Value = k

                cRow = cRow + 1
            Next k
        Next j
    Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This routine illustrates how to solve.  It generates string tuples "3,4,1" but you can amend to use arrays if you like. Not easy to read, but if you step thru all will be clear.  For compactness, I did NOT declare variables, so run WITHOUT Option Explicit.

```
Const T = 3 ' generate 3-tuples
Const N = 6 ' using digits 1,...,6

Private Sub Permute()
    Dim cTuples As New Collection: Call cTuples.Add(Empty)      ' start w empty tuple (rank 0)
    For i = 1 To T: Set cTuples = NewTuples(cTuples, N): Next i ' increase tuple rank T times using N digits
    For Each vTuple In cTuples: Debug.Print vTuple: Next        ' display the results
End Sub

' helper func: turn a set of T-tuples into T+1 tuples
Private Function NewTuples(Tuples As Collection, N As Integer) As Collection
    Set NewTuples = New Collection
    For Each vOldTuple In Tuples
        For i = 1 To N: NewTuples.Add (AppendToTuple(vOldTuple, i)): Next
    Next
End Function

' helper func: turn a single T tuple into a T+1 tuple
Private Function AppendToTuple(Tuple, i)
    If IsEmpty(Tuple) Then AppendToTuple = i Else AppendToTuple = Tuple & "," & i
End Function
```

Resulting string tuples debug.print'ed to Immed Window (ctrl-G):

```
1,1,1
1,1,2
1,1,3
1,1,4
1,1,5
1,1,6
1,2,1
1,2,2
...
6,6,5
6,6,6
```